# How to create an alias for ctags in vimscript

Tags: vim

I have a function that is invoked based on a simple key mapping

```
function! JumpToDefinition()
    let filetype=&ft
    if filetype == 'coffee'
        exe '<C-]>'
    endif
endfunction
```

This works when I manually do `<C-]>` but when I try to "exe" it above I get a "trailing whitespace" error.

How can I invoke this in a standalone function like I have above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note  that [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3aexecute)  runs the  resulting expression  as an  Ex command,
which isn't probably what  you want since there is no  `<C-]>` Ex command. You
should be using [`:normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal).

However, to  be able to  use these "special  keys", instead of  the characters
they represent, you have to pay attention to three things:

1. The correct way to represent them  is with a backslash `\<xxx>`. Check the
   help for [`expr-string`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-string).
2. Use double quotes, not single quotes
3. `:normal` accepts commands, not an expression like `:execute`

So, from items 1  and 2 above we know that `"\<C-]>"` should  be used, but you
can't put  this in  front of  `:normal`. Well, you  can, but  then it  will be
executed as "quote,  backslash, C, ...". The  solution is to go  back to using
`:execute`, this time to build the string with the visible `"\<xxx>"` in front
of `:normal`, which will be expanded to the actual character and executed.

```
:exe "norm \<C-]>"
```

Comment: @ToranBillups You're welcome :-) I hope that it helps clarifying what was happening